# Percentage always equal to 0

Tags: java

I have this method. It basically uses popup windows to display simple addition questions:

```
public static void addition ()
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "++ You chose Addition! ++");
    double percentage;
    String rank = "";
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (true){
      int add1 = (int)(Math.random()*9) + 1;
      int add2 = (int)(Math.random()*9) + 1;

      i = i + 1;

      int addtotal = add1 + add2;

      try{
        String test = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, i + "). What's " + add1 + " + " + add2 + "?");


        if (test == null){
          choose();
        }

        int convertToNum = Integer.parseInt (test);

        if (convertToNum == addtotal){ // if the user got it right
          x++;
          final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/tick_64.png")); //Custom Icon for the JFrame below, The image destination uses a URL link to show the icon
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nice Job!\nYou Currently Got " + x + " Out of " + i + " Correct!",":D",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon);
        }
        else { // if the user got it wrong
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Sorry, but that was wrong.\n" + add1 + " + " + add2 + " = " + addtotal + " . \n You Currently Got " + x + " Out of " + i + " Correct!","Whoops",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          y++;
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "I Didn't Understand That.","...",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        y++;
      }

      System.out.println ("x: " +x); 
      System.out.println ("i: " +i);

      percentage = (x - y) / i * 100;
      System.out.println ("% :" + percentage);
    }
  }
```

Say I keep getting perfect, Then `percentage = 100.0` when displayed on the interactions pane. HOWEVER when I get **one** question wrong, instead of getting a percentage number, i automatically get a zero (ex say I got 2 out of 3, `percentage = 0` instead of `percentage = 66.6`. I tried getting rid of the 0 when declaring it, but it only gives me "variable may not have been initialized".

Comment: use doubles, for a start

Answer (score 1):

cast one of the integer operands inside the bracket to `double` to make use of floating point arithmetic .

```
double percentage = ((double)x - y) / i * 100;
```

All operands (x,y,i and literal 100) are integers, therefore integer arithmetic division is used which will remove everything after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to integer arithmetic.

Try `percentage = ((double)x - y) / i * 100;`

From the [Chapter 15](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) :

> The type of a multiplicative expression is the promoted type of its
>   operands. 
>  
>   If the promoted type is int or long, then integer arithmetic
>   is performed. 
> If the promoted type is float or double, then
>   floating-point arithmetic is performed.

Comment: Where is "integer arithmetic" defined exactly in the JLS?

Comment: @ingyhere http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17 (see 15.17.2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with dividing ints is Java truncates the decimal portion. You can either make `x` and `y` floating point variables or just cast them to float for doing the division and cast them back to get an int as the final result.